# Delphi 2010 AutoRun Tab Error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Many versions of Delphi including Delphi 2010 display" Error executing 'D:\ProgramData{BBD31133-40F8-4B57-9BA6-DB76C03D153B}\Setup.exe': The parameter is incorrect in the AutoRun Tab."

What does it mean and how do you eliminate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell Delphi to not check for updates upon startup - I believe you have to do that in the installer (doing a repair should be good enough, I think), or go into the registry and change it manually. The alternative is running the IDE as an administrator.

It's a conflict between the privileges Vista believes the update checker requires (due to the filename, apparently) and the privileges the IDE has, causing UAC to prevent the executable from being launched automatically (unfortunately, the error message returned doesn't really make much sense in the context).

Comment: Does running as administrator solve the problem? The message appears in the IDE (trial version) even when started with an Administrator account.

Comment: Keep in mind that unless you have UAC turned off, programs don't run with admin privileges in Vista and 7 even with an admin account. If you get the problem while explicitly choosing "Run as admin" from a right-click menu, or change the properties of the EXE/shortcut to always use admin privileges, it will basically run as though you were a regular, limited user.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum to @michaels's answer:

Open regedit.exe and navigate to the following registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\AutoRun\UpdateCheck

Find the Name ProgramToRun and simply modify and set the value to an empty string.